# Make Gameobject bob up and down frame rate independently (2D)

Tags: unity-game-engine

How would I make a game object with a randomly generated position move up and down to give the game more of an alive feeling?

So the Y value should look like this:

original -> original + 1f -> original

I want to do this from a script and I want it to be frame rate independent.

Thanks!

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Something like `transform.position.y = startY + Mathf.Sin(Time.deltaTime) * speed;`.

Comment: @George I don't think that you can directly set the Y value of the position. Using the Mathf.Sin can be nice and creative though.

Comment: @Rhach Ah right, i'm not super familiar with unity - I guess `transform.position = startPos + Vector3.Up * Mathf.Sin(Time.deltaTime) * speed;`  is probably closer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frame rate independent sounds very good, but as far as I know, `FixedUpdate` should be used for physics calculations, where you cannot rely on the `Time.deltaTime` as it is not constant, and the physics calculation usually require a precise delta-time, or "step" for the physics solver. [Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) also advices so.

So I would not go for the fixed update with the idea of that the movement needed needs to be constant, unaltered and good looking. As far as I know, the scene elements and their movement should be handled in the normal `Update` if physics are not involved (apart from the camera follow movements which are recomended to be in the [LateUpdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html).)

Find below and example that can be used for vertical animation as a kind of idle. It can be changed to the `FixedUpdate` if desired, although it does not seem technically correct.

```
public class IdleVerticalMovement: MonoBehaviour
{
    float speed = 0.01f;
    
    Update() {
        transform.localPosition += new Vector3(0, Mathf.Sin(Time.time) * speed, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer, I just find it hard to delete my own answer. I spent more than 3 minutes writing that thing :P

Comment: Just to appease the optimization freak inside me, I would say: transform.localPosition += Vector3.up * Mathf.Sin(Time.time) * speed; is slightly more performant.

Answer (score 1):

Not on pc, so, there could be errors, but it should probably be something like this:

```
private bool goingUp = false;
private float speed = 2.0f; // This is the bobing speed
private upperLimit = 1.0f;
private lowerLimit = -1.0f;

private void Update()
{
    if(goingUp)
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.Up * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        if(transform.position.y > upperLimit)
        {
            goingUp = false;
        }
    }else
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.Down * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        if(transform.position.y < lowerLimit)
        {
            goingUp = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That is what the `FixedUpdate()` handler is for, it gets called at the physics rate that does not depend on frame rate. Just put your random calculation in there.

See `MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate()` in the scripting documentation.

Edit: A proper "head bob" is sinuzuidal and not random.

Comment: FixedUpdate is indeed used for physics. However, when the OP needs can be handled without relying on the physics system. The Time.deltaTime is used to make something frame independant.